# TDBLookupComboBox in delphi doesn't scroll properly

Tags: delphi

My `TDBLookupComboBox` in delphi has a bug when scrolling. The picture will explain better.

[image: TDBLookupComboBox scroll]

There are more than 200 items in my `dblkComboBox`. When I open it by clicking in the right drop down it starts with the scroll bar in the middle. Then,

1. I can't browse the items using the mouse scrolling property.
2. The scrollbar is stuck in the middle, no matter if I am in the first item or in the 150º item the scrollbar is always in the middle.
3. The scrollbar only changes its position when I go to the last item, then the scrollbar goes to the bottom.
4. I am able to select items and to keep going in my app, however this bug gives a very weird experience for the user.

I add the info the the ComboBox with the code below (although I don't think this may cause the problme)

```
with qryUF do
begin
  Connection := dmDados.FDConnection;
  Active := False;
  SQL.Clear;
  Open('SELECT * FROM estado');
end;

dblkcbbUF.ListSource := dsUF;
dblkcbbUF.ListField := C_UF;
dblkcbbUF.KeyField := C_UF;
dblkcbbUF.KeyValue := qryUF.FieldByName(C_UF).AsVariant;
```

And some of the properties of my TDBLookupComboBox

dblkcbb.

Any way to make it more smooth with good scrolling and with the scrollbar showing the real position of the items?

Comment: Any weird settings from the properties window?

Comment: Is your dblkComboBox of type TDBLookUpComboBox, or same 3rd party alternative?  Reason I ask is that with a standard TDBLookUpCombox with 300 look-up items I don't see your problem.  So I think you need to add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q, otherwise it should be closed, because readers needs to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin All the properties are the default one.

Comment: A, OK. I get cases like this when the real cause was that the programmer changed one or more properties then forgot about it.

Comment: @MartynA It is a TDBLookUpComboBox from delphi. Thank you for the article and sorry for not asking properly. I added the code I use to populate the items the ComboBox, and the properties are the default ones. However, I am know thinking that maybe the behavior I see in the combobox is the normal one. In the first item the scrollbar is in the top, in the last item it is in the bottom, in all the other items it is in the center. Last, by scrolling with two fingers in the trackpad I can't scroll the ComboBox, but I know think that maybe this is the normal behavior of vcl application.

Comment: IIRC the dataset has to provide a valid RecNo to make the scrollbar work. Not every dataset descendant supports this.

Comment: This could very well be the case , especially if you only use a query and not a ClientDataset as the source. Querys usually dont know how many rows they have and so they cant give an estimation for the scrollbar. I would try using a Clientdataset instead of a query.